# C++ unordered_map doesn't find values from command line arguments

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, unordered-map

I'm working on a C++ program involving the periodic table.  I have a `Table` class with a vector holding pointers to all of the element objects and an unordered_map that converts element names and symbols into atomic numbers.  It overloads the [] operator so that `Table[const char*]` returns a pointer to the element with the specified name or symbol.  This works just fine if I hard-code the name or symbol into the call like `Table["H"]`, but if I call the program like `./program H` and try `Table argv[1]` there is an out_of_range error even though H is in the Table and `Table["H"]` works fine.  Why doesn't it find elements by symbol when the symbol is a command line argument but it does when the symbol is hard-coded?

Here is my code with only one element to keep it as simple as possible:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Element{
public:
    const char* name;//name
    const char* sym;//symbol
    const int z;//atomic number
    const double m;//atomic mass
    const double p;//density
    const double mP;//melting point
    const double bP;//boiling point
    const double c;//specific heat
    const double eneg;//electonegativity
    const int gp;//group
    const int pd;//period
    Element(const char* n,const char* s,const int an,const double am,
            const double d,const double mp,const double b,
            const double sh,const double e,const int g,const int pd):
        name(n),sym(s),z(an),m(am),p(d),mP(mp),bP(b),c(sh),eneg(e),gp(g),pd(pd)
        {}
    Element(const Element& e):
        name(e.name),sym(e.sym),z(e.z),m(e.m),p(e.p),mP(e.mP),bP(e.bP),c(e.c),
        eneg(e.eneg),gp(e.gp),pd(e.pd)
        {}
    const Element& operator=(const Element& e){
        return e;
    }
};

Element ah("Surprise","Ah",0,0.0625,0.000001,4999 ,9998,999999,0,0,0);
Element* undiscovered=&ah;

class Table{
public:
    vector<const Element*> E_n;//vector<Element> E_n;
    unordered_map<const char*,int>E_ns;
    const Element* operator[](int i){
        return E_n[i];
    }
    const Element* operator[](const char* n){
        try{
            return E_n[E_ns.at(n)];
        }catch(out_of_range e){
            return undiscovered;
        }
    }
    int size(){
        return E_n.size();
    }
    void add(const Element& e){
        while(E_n.size()<=e.z)E_n.push_back(undiscovered);
        E_n[e.z]=&e;
        E_ns[e.name]=e.z;
        E_ns[e.sym]=e.z;
    }
    void print(){
        puts("\n");
        for(auto e:E_n){
            printf("%3d %13s(%3s). m:%7.3f, p:%10f, mp:%7.2f, bp:%7.2f\n",e->z,e->name,e->sym,e->m,e->p,e->mP,e->bP);
        }
    }
};

Table Elements;

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    int i;
    Elements.add(Element("Hydrogen","H",1,1.008,0.00009,14.1,20.28,14.304,2.20,1,1));
    i=Elements[argv[1]]->z;
    if(!i)i=atoi(argv[1]);
    if(!i){
        printf("There is no element \"%s\".\n",argv[1]);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("%f\n",Elements[i]->m);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Off topic, but nevertheless: give your variables meaningful names. Density is 'density' or at least 'rho'. Thank me later ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two `const char *`s are not equal since one points to a constant and the other doesn't. Since you indexed the map using a pointer, the pointers would have to be equal for the `find` to succeed. Instead, index the map using a `std::string` so that equal strings will locate the element.